# How to register Microsoft Logger with Serilog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, serilog, .net-4.7.2

I have Full .NET 4.7.2 application that use `Serilog 2.10` for logging. However all the classes have dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

   public MyClass(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyClass> logger)
   {
      _logger = logger;
   }
}
```

I want microsoft's `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>` implementation to call into Serilog. So  I am using [Serilog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging) `3.0.1` to register logger.

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();

        Serilog.Log.Logger = logger;          
       

         //also register microsoft.extensions.logging.Ilogger
         var logger = new SerilogLoggerProvider(Serilog.Log.Logger).CreateLogger("MyApp");
         container.RegisterInstance(logger);
     }
```

The above registration can inject and works with Microsoft's `ILogger` but fails for `ILogger<T>` with error

> The current type, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[MyClass], is
> an interface and cannot be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

The Unity Container doesn't know how to resolve open generics that are not registered, so you'll need to use the [Unity.Microsoft.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Microsoft.Logging) extension for Unity which takes care of resolving `ILogger<T>` for the container.

> `Install-Package Unity.Microsoft.Logging`

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(new LoggingExtension());

var loggerProvider = new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger).CreateLogger("MyApp");
container.RegisterInstance(loggerProvider);
// ...
```